# How are adapters used in django-allauth?

Tags: python, django, authentication, google-signin, django-allauth

Hi everyone this is my first post on StackOverflow.

I'm building a web application using Django and **I would like to:**

- Only allow people that have a Google account to sign up / log in
- Only people with a specific email domain can access the web app and their UserModel will be saved to the database.

I started with coding a middleware, and it worked, I managed to log out those that tried to log in with a Google account associated with a not allowed email BUT they were saved in the database User model.

I then found out about Adapters (for django-allauth) and I saw I could use them to achieve my goals but in the documentation, they are only cited once.

I then started looking at the GitHub [repo](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/blob/master/allauth/socialaccount/adapter.py) and found some more info but I'm still not able to implement this myself.

Can anyone help me?

Btw this is my code so far:

**Disclaimer**:

*This code does not work, it's not even called when I try to test it. ( I tried to log in with a wrong Google account to see it it gets triggered but nothing appened)*

**main_app/adapters.py**

```
from allauth.socialaccount.adapter import DefaultSocialAccountAdapter
from allauth.account.adapter import DefaultAccountAdapter


class DisableSignupAdapter(DefaultAccountAdapter):
    def is_open_for_signup(self, request):
        return False


class UgaSocialAccountAdapter(DefaultSocialAccountAdapter):

    def pre_social_login(self, request, sociallogin):
        # abort if email does not end with @uga.com
        if not sociallogin.user.email.endswith("@uga.com"):
            print("Email domain must be uga.com")
            raise PermissionError("Email domain must be jeupo.com")
        else:
            print("Email domain is uga.com")
            return super().pre_social_login(request, sociallogin)

    def is_open_for_signup(self, request, sociallogin):
        return True
```

**settings.py**

```
DEFAULT_ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'main_app.adapter.DisableSignupAdapter'
DEFAULT_SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'main_app.adapter.UgaSocialAccountAdapter'
```

**Things I tried:**

- Middleware -> Was a good try but still saved wrong users to the database
- Adapters -> Does not even get called :/

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your settings:

```py
ACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'main_app.adapter.DisableSignupAdapter'
SOCIALACCOUNT_ADAPTER = 'main_app.adapter.UgaSocialAccountAdapter'
```

without `DEFAULT`